# Is it possible to Run a Kivy app without the console window showing?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I have a basic Kivy app written in Python 3.6 to help produce simple mailing labels with reportlab. How do I get it to the script to run without showing the console window?

We're using it on windows 7, 8.1 and 10. It would be far more aesthetic if the console window wasn't shown but using a .pyw extension the kivy window fails to load.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

With thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO: You are encouraged to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help/) and pay special attention to the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) portion to learn what constitutes a good question increasing the probability of getting a good answer. Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

If you use PyInstaller to package your app for windows:
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html

There is a command line tag -noconsole which will achieve what you are looking for.